# How to send data to website from GPS device using gprs?

Tags: web, gps, gprs

I had planned to do mini project. With GPS modem using GPRS(sim card with internet connection) and i need to send the data from GPS modem to a website. Is it possible? If so how it can be done? What are the languages needed? And also tell me about the best GPS device?

Answer (score 0):

GPS devices communicate using a standard protocol called the NMEA protocol.

Assuming you are using .NET you can check out the Positioning code in the DotSpatial open source project: http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/

They've got classes to decode the NMEA strings and can probably do much of what you are describing out of the box.

As for the best GPS device, if you need standard resolutions, any GPS device will do.  They can be had for 10's of dollars.  We often use the USGlobalSat model BU-353, although this is USB so it may not work in your application.

Answer (score 0):

For what you want u must do 2 things
1. Create a TCP Listener which will wait for info using TCP in same port and put into database
2. Create a web or windows application for you read from database.

i have done something like this in my recent project.

Regards.